# Unable to cleanly set GOOS environment variable on win7

Tags: windows, go

I am trying to use golangs cross compilation feature to compile on my machine (windows 7) to switch between compiling for linux and amd64.

I set up everything properly and created the enviroment variables

```
GOARCH = amd64
GOOS = linux
```

My problem occurs whenever I try to switch between platforms by changing GOOS to either linux or amd64. I use [Console 2](http://sourceforge.net/projects/console/) to manage my standart cmd, cygwin console and git console.
After changing GOOS with:

```
xset GOOS=amd64
```

different consoles show different values for the variable e.g:

```
//git bash
echo $GOOS
linux
//cmd
echo %GOOS%
amd64
```

This happens even after restarting all consoles.
Additionally I am suddenly unable to access parts of my system!
Trying to access my "Advanced System settings" in my System properties returns now a warning:

```
"%windir%\system32\systempropertiesadvanced.exe" could not be found.
```

which sounds to my like win7 suddenly can't handle its own environment variables anymore.

This also means that I can't change the variables through the windows GUI anymore.

On top of all that the "go" command is no longer bound and I am unable to build anything with go.

My only solution this far is to restart my entire system every time I change a variable.
After a restart the variable is changed an everything works fine until I want to change GOOS again.

I would be very happy about any kind of input, I am new to go and assume that I am missing something obvious.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Have you tried using `set` or cygwin's `env` instead of `xset`? It could be an issue with that program.

Comment: @JeremiahWinsley I tried `set` before and moved on to `xset` hoping it would fix my issues. I will try `env`though.

Comment: @Bricktop if you are only using this setting for compiling, I would recommend 2 tricks that I use.  The first is to set it per command e.g. `GOOS=linux go build xxx` and when I have to do this kind of thing too often then I build a script.  Personally I find that my environment gets less corrupted this way.

Comment: @CoreyScott I built two scripts to switch between windows and linux. Unfortunatly that didn't help but Philipp Franke pointed me in the right direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps you should check your environment variables, especially it's length.

If your environment variables hit the maximum size, windows can't access the env variables properly so it leads to your error message.

Further information:
[Environment Variables](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682653(v=vs.85).aspx)
[What happens with Path System Variable is too long?](http://programmersadventure.blogspot.de/2013/11/what-happens-with-path-system-variable.html)

Comment: Thanks, this was actually my problem.
I removed some unneeded parts of my PATH variable and everything worked like a charm afterwards.
Pretty weird reason but atleast it's fixed now.